# Woocommerce add filter conditions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the filter `woocommerce_get_price` which rounds up products price.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1); 

    function round_price_product() {
    //code and returns rounded price

    }
```

I want to remove this filter from certain products.

For example product 1, product 2, product 3 all use the filter `woocommerce_get_price` and their prices are all rounded.

For product 4 & 5 i don't want the filter to be used.

How do i omit filters from certain products?

Answer (score 0):

try following plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/

i hope it will work.